# Is email regex pattern suggested by W3C spec prone to ReDoS attacks?

Tags: regex, sonarqube

This is the regex pattern suggested for email validation by the [W3C HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$
```

SonarQube flags it as "vulnerable to a denial of service attack (ReDOS)".
I think it's a false positive, but I'm no expert on this field and I might be missing something.

I believe Sonar thinks it might be susceptible to ReDoS attacks due to nesting repetitions - `[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}` contained in the group followed by the asterisk. But still, I think that when regex engine backtracks this expression it can resolve it quickly as either dot or end of the line is expected afterward. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: OK just read the W3C spec and would like to add that despite everything it says it would disallow this valid email address `João.Lourenço@gov.ao`  which would make it difficult to email Angola's president. :-)

Comment: @JGNI it would also disallow `example@яндекс.рф` which it also says its valid. It is, however, supposed to work on the punycode string, so if you enter that email, the idea is that if you enter that in an `email` input, it would *actually* be checking `xn--joo-nla.xn--loureno@gov-r9a.ao` but the browser should format and present that as `João.Lourenço@gov.ao` to the user.

Comment: @vlaz I've just been back to the W3C site and there is a long discussion at https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/845 about this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sonar isn't that smart. It sees quantified groups that include quantified patterns. Although it's the main reason for a ReDoS attack to take place, that's not enough.

The suspicious regular expression in question has a boundary:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*
                                                 ^
```

That boundary makes a failure to happen earlier (see what [happens without it](https://regex101.com/r/tE6u2g/1)). If it wasn't there then we could say Sonar is a hundred percent right. Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding is clear - Sonar complains because it sees (simplified) `(ab(b*b)?)*` but the presence of `a` negates the concern. Is that correct?

Comment: @vlaz Sonar most probably sees `(...{0,61}...?)*`. It doesn't recognize all patterns. It recognizes quantifiers. Your simplified version should be `ab*(\.ab*)*`. Here the presence of `.` negates the concern.